# Django admin saves unicode wrong

Tags: django, oracle, unicode, django-models, django-admin

Guys when I save something in unicode (for example something in armenian language like `մեկ`) in django admin it saves like this '???'.
I'm using Django 1.9 and the database is Oracle 11gR2 with `NLS_CHARACTERSET -  WE8MSWIN1252` and  `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET - AL16UTF16`. Inside DB I can store Unicode data and my table column is of `nvarchar2` datatype. 
My Model is:

```
class ChoiceFieldsParams(models.Model):
    param_desc = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False,blank=False)

    class Meta:
        managed=True
        db_table='choice_field_params'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.param_desc
```

In my admin i have the following.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import ChoiceFieldsParams

admin.site.register(ChoiceFieldsParams)
```

Can anybody mention where  the problem is?

Comment: Are you running Django in Python 2 or Python 3 ?

Comment: @sers i'm running on python 3.5.1